# Render in infinity loop

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

Question for Python 2.6

I would like to create an *simple* web application which in specified time interval will run a script that modifies the data (in database). My problem is code for *infinity loop* or some other method to achieve this goal. The script should be run only once by the user. Next iterations should run automatically, even when the user leaves the application. If someone have idea for method detecting apps breaks it would be great to show it too. I think that threads can be the best way to achive that. Unfortunately, I just started my adventure with Python and don't know yet how to use them.

The application will have also views *showing* database and for control of *loop script*.

Any ideas?

Comment: What web framework are you using? Django?

Comment: You can't run an infinite loop on GAE, the request would timeout, so it was kind of important to mention. Kevin's answer is the best way to do it on GAE

Comment: You can't use a thread because threading is not available on GAE http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#libraries

Comment: GAE restrictions is not a problem. GAE is not final framework for this project.

Comment: If anyone knows an alternative for *cron* (functionality) to use in/by Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that you're using Google App Engine.  You can schedule recurring tasks by placing a `cron.yaml` file in your application folder.  The details are [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html).

**Update**: It sounds like you're not looking for GAE-specific solutions, so the more general advice I'd give is to use the native scheduling abilities of whatever platform you're using.  Cron jobs on a *nix host, scheduled tasks on Windows, `cron.yaml` on GAE, etc.

In your other comments you've suggested wanting something in Python that doesn't leave your script executing, and I don't think there's any way to do this.  Some process has to be responsible for kicking off whatever it is you need done, so either you do it in Python and keep a process executing (even if it's just `sleep`ing), or you use the platform's scheduling tools.  The OS is almost guaranteed to do a better job of this than your code.

Comment: I thought that there would have to be an answer along these lines... I think we have a winner!

Answer (score 1):

i think you'd want to use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).  write your script, and have [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) run it every X minutes / hours.

if you really want to do this in Python, you can do something like this:

```
while(True):
    <your app logic here>
    sleep(TIME_INTERVAL)
```

Comment: Work incorrect in my case. Sleep method increase time of script *execution*. Is there any *corn* writed in python?

Comment: why do you need cron to be written in python?

Comment: I don't need cron (in Python) but simple solution with functionality like cron. I would like to have all the application controled by Python code and don't care if cron is instaled on server or not. But it seems that cron is the best solution...

Comment: if you're on google app engine: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you use cron to schedule the job to run at certain intervals? It's usually considered better than infinite loops, and was designed to help solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very primitive *cron* in the Python standard library: [`import sched`](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html).  There's also [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Timer).

But as others say, you probably should just use the real *cron*.

Comment: Could you tell more? How to use them in my case? Is this method *prevent script timeout*?

Comment: No. If you're on GAE you definitely want Kevin's answer.